# Matlab Determine the start of a signal

Tags: matlab

I obtained a signal like below and it is a digitized signal:

[image]

I would like to determine the start point of signal with MATLAB.  One idea in my mind is to use the time-frequency transform to determine when the new component of frequency arises. However, I don't know how to proceed with this in MATLAB.

Here is the data associated with this signal - https://www.dropbox.com/s/16gqlvi7obkb4nk/sig.txt

Comment: Why did you remove it? If its an image, post it in imageshank and put the link, we will put the image, if its data, put the data

Comment: How do you expect us to answer this question? We have no Idea what kind of signal you got. Do you have noise, do you have an offset, do you have sth. with a sine (sth which is repeated). Right now we would have to guess so many things. If you don't want to (or are not allowed to) upload the image and post the link as @AnderBiguri said, at least try to describe the signal or even better if you created it yourself or know what it should look like (e.g. sine) post the code/formula.

Comment: @user3790569 - Please provide a link where we can download the signal.  With a question like this, we need to have the actual data to work on before we proceed and answer.

Comment: @user3790569 - If you want to do time-frequency decomposition, take a look at [`specgram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html)

Comment: @user3790569 - Stop removing the image from your post.  I have left it there so it better explains your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am a new registered user, so not allowed to post image here.

Comment: So am I right, that you want the signal starting with the absolut maximum peak? If so just use an if-case to determine the first y-value which is outside of noise...Lets say your y-ticks are unit of 5 and the signal oszilates around 0. Just use a for-loop (starting first element) and a if-case (`if y(k) > 5 start_element=k; break end`.

Comment: I guess you can do this by using continuous wavelet decomposition of time series. Here is the code:

    [~,i]=max(cwt(a,1:16,'db4'),[],2);
    start_point=min(i);

**In the time series posted here along with the question, the start point of the new frequency in the signal is,** `103`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can go about it.

```
[~,i]=max(cwt(a,1:16,'db4'),[],2); 
start_point=min(i);
```

Applying the above code and plotting the `"start_point"` on the time series gives the following image:

[image: The red asterik (*) marks the start of the signal]

**The red asterik (*) marks the start of the signal.** Please note that if you have multiple start points in a single time series, you might take into consideration local maxima's above a certain threshold. Please go through the help for `"cwt"` and choose the scales and mother wavelet which suits you.

Comment: Thanks. It looks pretty like what I want. If I need to determine the uncertainty with the start point, how could I determine it? In your script, it is based on continuous wavelet transform.

Comment: What do you mean by uncertainity? If there is any algorithm please let me know. As I am a biologist my knowledge about signal analysis is limited.

Comment: In time-frequency analysis, the time calculated for certain frequency is always bond with uncertainty. I am physicist, I also have no knowledge about signal processing

Comment: @Schoner Cat, if you are asking about the uncertainity due to conversion of time domain into frequency domain and back during the determination of the start of a frequency, my answer would be that unlike FFT, wavelet transform analyzes the frequency properties of a signal with out disturbing the temporal characteristics. Therefore, I guess that you don't have to worry about the uncertainity in calculation.